# Entity framework 6 many to many adding doesn't work on both sides

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Say I have the following models:

```
public class Letter 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public List<Folder> Folders {get;set;}
}

public class Folder 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public List<Letter> Letters {get; set;}
}

 public class ProjectDbContext : DbContext
 {
       public class ProjectDbContext()
      {
             Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      }
  }
```

The relation is configured from the letter side as follows:

```
 public class LetterConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Letter> 
{
       public LetterConfiguration()
     {
           HasMany(x =>             x.Folders).WithMany().Map(configuration =>
         {
             configuration.MapLeftKey(LetterId);
             configuration.MapRightKey(FolderId);
         }
     }
 }
```

Now the example: 
Empty database with seeded folders. 
If I call those two methods one after another, I get no letters at all:

```
 public class LettersDataAccess()
{
      public void AddLettersToFolder(int[] letters, Folder folder
     {
            var databaseLetters = _DbSet.Include(l => l.Folders).where(x => letters.contains(x.Id));

            foreach (var letter in databaseLetters)
            { 
                  // The folder is one I receieved erlier from the database, and therefore should be tracked
                  letter.Folders.Add(folder)
            }

            SaveChanges();
      }
}

 public class FoldersDataAccess()
{
      public List<Letter> GetFolderLetters(int folderId)
     {
             Folder folder =_dbSet.Include(f =>  f.Letters).First(f => f.Id ==folderId)

            // returns no results
           return folder.Letters;
      }
}
```

Now my question is:
If I add a letter and set it's Folders list to existing foldera in my system, will this letter automatically be added to the list of letters of those folders?

Or should the adding always be two sided? How is that supposed to work? I was hoping it worked the first way but seems that it doesn't.

I hope someone could guide me here.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: I did and it didn't work as I expect, wanted to know if thats the usual behaviour or if something is wrong with my code or configiration